# What is the best way to link an image with a mongodb item?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently building my first real project that includes Express and MongoDB. Since it's one of the first backend-heavy projects I've worked on outside of my Udemy course, I've run into a lot of questions.

My project is supposed to be a mock-online store that would display items I have created inside of my MongoDB server. The problem I'm having is that I don't know the proper way of serving those image files that should be associated with each item (such as the image of a hat, for a hat item). I could add them directly into the project's public folder, but I don't know if that would be feasible in terms of the scalability that I want this project to demonstrate. But it doesn't seem like MongoDB will let me store images within each item. How would I go about doing that?

Sorry in advance if any of this is unclear, it's my first time posting as well. I'll try and provide more information if I need too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scalable solution for images, you typically would use a separate service like AWS S3 or Imgix.

There are several benefits to using a 3rd party service. You don't bog down your web server with image requests, or image resizing. You get virtually unlimited space. Etc.

In your MongoDB document, you would then store a key like `/item/1.jpg` or whatever, rather than the image itself. Your front-end then uses the key to request the image when someone visits your website.

If you want a turn-key solution, I recommend starting with Imgix (or Cloudinary, or some similar service). It is more expensive than S3, but it is pretty cheap for a small project, and it will get you up and running a lot faster.